# Calculating growth rate in Mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

Hello I have this query to get rate based in previous row:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  100 * (Volumen - Volumen_a) / (Volumen_a) Subida
FROM (
  SELECT
   *,
   (
     SELECT Volumen
     FROM ejemplo t_ant
     WHERE
       t_ant.Sujeto = t_act.Sujeto AND t_ant.Id < t_act.Id
     ORDER BY Id DESC
     LIMIT 1
   ) Volumen_a
  FROM ejemplo t_act
  WHERE Sujeto = 'HGT'
  ORDER BY Fecha DESC
  LIMIT 1
) t
WHERE Volumen_a IS NOT NULL;
```

It's just showing the last row... then I need it show me all rows.

Best regards

Comment: What would happen if  LIMIT 1 is removed on the 3rd to last line?

Comment: It's working, was necessary to delete where name clausule too, kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  100 * (Volumen - Volumen_a) / (Volumen_a) Subida
FROM (
  SELECT
   *,
   (
     SELECT Volumen
     FROM ejemplo t_ant
     WHERE
       t_ant.Sujeto = t_act.Sujeto AND t_ant.Id < t_act.Id
     ORDER BY Id DESC
     LIMIT 1
   ) Volumen_a
  FROM ejemplo t_act
  ORDER BY Fecha DESC
  ) t
WHERE Volumen_a IS NOT NULL;
```

Resolved deleting last limit 1 and where name clausule.
Thank you